# Why is C platform-dependent?

Tags: c

Why does C have to be recompiled for each architecture? Doesn't it all end up as bits and bytes and loads and jumps anyway? Doesn't each architecture essentially go through the most basic commands in the same way?

Comment: C is mid-level-language :)

Comment: Quantify "architecture". (Do you think an x86 chip uses the same instructions as a ARM chip, for example.)

Comment: `Doesn't each architecture essentially go through the most basic commands in the same way?` ***Not really***. Definitely not in the *exact* same way, which is what platform-independence means.

Comment: Because different architectures work differently, so the binary works differently. Otherwise it'd be like using an nVidia driver for an ATI graphics card!

Comment: [Why is C++ platform dependent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810484/why-is-c-platform-dependent)

Comment: Why C, specifically? The question is basically why are all binaries not compatible with all computers.

Comment: [Platform independent languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607400/platform-independent-languages)

Comment: bits 'n' bytes maybe - but semantics my dear boy. Consider a byte containing 65. Is it the letter A, the number 65, or the 65th element in an array .....

Comment: C is platform independent at source code level.

Comment: [Why c language is platform dependent?](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_c_language_is_platform_dependent)

Comment: Why is DNA platform dependent? Why can't I mate with my dog? (at least: not make her pregnant ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Different CPUs have different instruction architectures (e.g., x86 vs ARM).

   - Early Macs used the Motorola 68k architecture; later ones used PowerPC; and still later ones used x86. During each of these transitions, developers had to ship their executables as [fat binaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary), which would contain object code for both architectures.
2. Current x86 CPUs have 32-bit and 64-bit modes.

   - This is why you have 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows, Ubuntu, etc.
3. Different operating systems provide different system calls, libraries, etc.

   - Different OS *versions* can provide different system calls, libraries, etc. also (although OS vendors do aim to be backward compatible as much as possible).
4. Even on the same operating system, the calling convention is not guaranteed to be the same between different compilers.

   - Even on the same OS, different executable file formats may be in use. For example, on many Unix systems, a.out used to be the format used, but most eventually switched to ELF. During the transition period, libraries had to be provided in both formats.

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't each architecture essentially go through the most basic commands in the same way?

For the most part. But those basic commands are [represented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) or [implemented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) differently. The C compiler is responsible for making sure that the correct representations and implementations are used.

Comment: this comment probably explained it best for me, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but all these loads and jumps etc. look different on different platforms. Each CPU family has its own command set.

On a higher level, if we have the same hardware but different OSes (such as Linux/Windows), we have different libraries, different executable file formats and so on.

All these are things which must be obeyed by the compiler and the linker.

Answer (score 1):

But every machine has its own [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set)

Comment: This is, at best, a comment.

Comment: @middaparka: This seems to be the answer, AFAICS.  (Albeit not a very detailed one.)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth One of them, yes.

Comment: A simple question deserves a simple answer.

Comment: An answer that basically consists of a link to off-site content is a poor answer, irrespective of the simplicity of the question.

Comment: @middaparka: In which case, downvote it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Each try to abstract some features, like every language do, needs to be tuned to the concrete architecture, or create a virtual machine (for each architecture) that can run it.